# Create a dynamic amount of columns for each item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, dynamic, model

I have a template maker which creates Scorecards with a possibility of having 10 sections with up to 10 questions in each. When creating my MVC View I only want to show sections that have questions. I have a column in my DB table that has a count of the sections and also for each section I have a column indicating the amount of questions in that section. I have tried this but the model binding does not like the insertion of dynamic names. I think it could be my syntax. Below is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {


                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartmentId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotSections)
                    </td>

                    @for (var i = 0; i < item.TotSections; i++ )
                    {
                        var section = 1;

                        var SN = "S" + section + "Name";
                        var SNUP = "S" + section + "NumUP";
                        var SNQ = "S" + section + "NumQuest";

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item[SN])
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item[SNUP])
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item[SNQ])
                        </td>
                    }

                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.TemplateId }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.TemplateId }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.TemplateId })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

IS there a way of doing this or do I need to rethink?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

If I had a Scorcard Template with one section in it the static table row would look like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <!--These are Constant for each item-->
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartmentId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotSections)
                    </td>

                    <!--BELOW IS WHERE I AM HAVING THE PROBLEM-->
                    <!--I want to create these columns dynamically,--> 
                    <!--depending on how many sections in column '**TotSections**' above-->
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.S1Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.S1NumUP)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.S1NumQuest)
                    </td>

                    <!--Below will be constant for each table row-->

                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.TemplateId }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.TemplateId }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.TemplateId })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

if there were two sections:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <!--These are Constant-->
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartmentId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotSections) 
                    </td>

                    <!--BELOW IS WHERE I AM HAVING THE PROBLEM-->
                    <!--I want to create these columns dynamically,--> 
                    <!--depending on how many sections in column '**TotSections**' above-->
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.S1Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.S1NumUP)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.S1NumQuest)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.S2Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.S2NumUP)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.S2NumQuest)
                    </td>

                    <!--Below will be constant-->

                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.TemplateId }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.TemplateId }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.TemplateId })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

The end view will look like this:

[image]

You can see above under the TotSections column:

**Test Template 1** has 1 section. If I display these with a static viewmodel, columns will be displayed when they shouldn't be and columns won't be displayed when they should. As in the above picture it is showing 2 sections worth when it only has one.

**Test Template 2** has 6 sections but is only displaying 2 of the six's columns so is missing 4 sections worth of columns.

The code I originally posted was my attempt to get the number of sections from item.TotSections and then create the section columns dynamically.

Hope this is a bit clearer

Comment: If the content is dynamic in any way, I generally build a view model that matches the view's requirements instead of the data. The purpose of a ViweModel is to act as a bridge for the view anyway. You can populate it from the data dynamically, if needed, but its properties are fixed so will work with the view.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. The Content is dynamic but also the columns for each section will also be dynamic as a template could have 2,3,4 or even 10 sections. I want to display a dynamic amount of columns for each item. In the above code i'm using a table but I might change this to display better on the page.

Comment: Can you please post a sample of the expected result so that the requirements are clearer? Thanks

Comment: Edited. Hope this is a bit clearer